# How to use Google Apps Script setAuthentication?

Tags: google-apps-script

So, I created an script on google sheets that, basically, selects a set of addresses on a sheet and uses `Maps.newGeocoder.geocode()` to get geocodes and calculate distances. It works wonderfully, no problems there. However, when I try to authenticate using `Maps.setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey);`, I just get an error.

I got my credentials from loging into https://console.cloud.google.com/, creating a random project and by going in "Create credentials". When I go into the credentials tab, I can select OAuth2.0 and see clientId and client secret key. I am using these to authenticate. Is it correct? What am I doing wrong? How the hell can I get the credentials? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have a Google Maps Premium Plan?

Comment: Personally, no. But the company I'm currently working for has. We use the api http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key and it works fine. I am migrating to Apps Scipt, so I have to use the Maps.setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey). Under OAuth2.0 I have clientId and client secret key. Are those the values I want? When I insert them, I get and authentication error.

Comment: Oh, when i try to use http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key directly from Google Sheets, it responds "This script can't access this API". How can I add this permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `setAuthentication(clientId, signingKey)` method enables the use of an externally established Google Maps APIs Premium Plan account, to leverage additional quota allowances. Your client ID and signing key can be obtained from the Google Enterprise Support Portal.

They are not the same as client ID and client secret key as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/apikey/overview).

Note that this type of account is not longer available for new customers.

Here some helpful links:

[Premium Plan Support](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support)

[Premium Plan FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/faq)